# Are you able to set a limit in google queries referencing a cell rather than a number?

Tags: google-sheets

When creating a query with limit returns. I would rather reference a cell to automatically set the limits rather than continuously using a numerical variable. Here is an example of what I was trying, obviously it didn't work! Any help would be greatly appreciated.  `=QUERY(Production,"SELECT * ORDER BY G DESC LIMIT (H11-H23)",1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(Production, "SELECT * ORDER BY G DESC LIMIT "&(H11-H23), 1)
```